# Algorithm to solve $L_1$ optimization of $\sum_i ||\mathbf{A_i x} - \mathbf{b_i}||_1$

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra

Is there is an efficient algorithm to solve the following optimization:

$\mathbf{x}^* = \arg\min_\mathbf{x}\sum_i ||\mathbf{A_i x} - \mathbf{b_i}||_1$

for given $\mathbf{b_i}, \mathbf{A_i}\ \forall i$, where $|| \mathbf{y} ||_1$ is the $L_1$ norm (i.e. $\sum_j |y_j|$) and $\mathbf{A_i}$ are big matrices which we don't have their explicit representations, only access to operations $\mathbf{A_i y}$ and $\mathbf{A_i^T z}$?

I can solve the problem for small matrices $\mathbf{A_i}$ using linear programming using the same trick from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103478/using-matlab-linear-programming-to-solve-compressed-sensing-minimization-problem), but if the matrices are large, there is no obvious way (at least for me) to solve it using linear programming.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for an algorithm which is more efficient than linear programming.

Comment: If you stack your matrices $\mathbf{A_i}$ and your vectors $\mathbf{b_i}$ together, can’t you reduce your problem to the case $n = 1$ (i.e., there is only one matrix/vector pair)?

Comment: I'm looking for algorithms that are more memory-efficient than linear programming. My problem is that the matrices are very large and it's almost impossible to store in memory. I only have access to the operations $A\cdot$ and $A^T\cdot$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer for this problem. One way is, as suggested in the comment, to stack the matrix $\mathbf{A_i}$ and $\mathbf{b_i}$ together and apply first-order convex optimization algorithm, such as [Primal-Dual Hybrid Gradient](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10851-010-0251-1) (PDHG), inexact ADMM, or their variants.

For PDHG, the problem to solve is

\begin{align}
\mathrm{min}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}} &~ F(\mathbf{y}) + G(\mathbf{x}) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} & ~ \mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{y}
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
F(\mathbf{y}) &= ||\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{b}||_1 \\
G(\mathbf{x}) &= 0 \\
\mathbf{A} &= [\mathbf{A_1}^T, \mathbf{A_2}^T, ..., \mathbf{A_n}^T]^T \\
\mathbf{b} &= [\mathbf{b_1}^T, \mathbf{b_2}^T, ..., \mathbf{b_n}^T]^T. \\
\end{align}

Thus, the convex conjugate of $F(\mathbf{y})$ is

\begin{align}
F^*(\mathbf{y}^*) &= \mathrm{sup}_{\mathbf{y}} \left[\left<\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}^*\right> - F(\mathbf{y})\right] \\
F^*(\mathbf{y}^*) &= \left<\mathbf{b},\mathbf{y^*}\right> + \mathcal{I}_{\mathbf{y^*}<\mathbf{b}}
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{I}_\mathcal{C}$ is an indicator function with value $0$ if the condition $\mathcal{C}$ fulfilled, otherwise $\infty$.

As the algorithm uses proximal operator, we need to get the proximal operator for $F$ and $G$,

\begin{align}
\mathrm{prox}_{F^*\sigma}(\mathbf{y}^*) &= \arg\min_{\mathbf{y}'}\left\{\frac{||\mathbf{y}'-\mathbf{y}^*||^2}{2\sigma} + F^*(\mathbf{y}^*)\right\} \\
\mathrm{prox}_{F^*\sigma}(\mathbf{y}^*) &= \max(\mathbf{y}^* + \sigma \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{b}) \\
\mathrm{prox}_{G\tau}(\mathbf{x}) &= \mathbf{x} \\
\end{align}

Thus, the algorithm in this case reads

\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}^{n+1} &= \max(\mathbf{y}^n + \sigma \mathbf{A} \mathbf{w}^n + \sigma \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{b}) \\
\mathbf{x}^{n+1} &= \mathbf{x}^n - \tau \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{y}^{n+1} \\
\mathbf{w}^{n+1} &= \mathbf{x}^{n+1} + \theta (\mathbf{x}^{n+1} - \mathbf{x}^n),
\end{align}

with $\theta = 1$, and $\sigma \tau ||A||^2 < 1$.

All the operations do not need the direct access to the element of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and only require the operation of $\mathbf{A} \cdot$ and $\mathbf{A}^T \cdot$.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to use [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent).  This will be memory-efficient, as you desired.  In particular, in each iteration we randomly pick an index $i$, then update $x$ based on the gradient of the function $f_i(x) = \| A_i x - b_i \|_1$, and repeat many times.  Each iteration only requires access to a single matrix $A_i$ at a time.